# CLOSED Magento collection OR condition

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I can do it now I used this code

```
->addAttributeToFilter('best_flag');

$collection->getSelect()->orwhere("at_best_flag. VALUE = '1'");
```

**Thank you everyone for your help**

How i can use OR condition in my code

**My problem code***

```
->addAttributeToFilter('best_flag', array('eq' => '1') )
```

but i test to getselect sql code is show

```
AND(at_best_flag. VALUE = '1')
```

I Want to change AND to OR can I set condition to this code?

**Update After Ask this question i try to use this code but not work**

```
->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute' =>'best_flag', array('eq' => '1')),
            array('attribute' =>'best_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate)),
            array('attribute' =>'best_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                ), 'left')   
        ))
```

but result is not match what i want result of date is not work because product ignore to date condition

i want to select product with by date and by flag in same collection

**EDIT PRODUCT LIST**

- all of product is 23
- in range of best from - best to = 10
- if only    have flag = 7 (just    not in range of from - to)
- if only    best from = 23
- if only best to    = 10
- correct Result for this collection will have 17

**Update code i will try**

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute' =>'best_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))),
            array('attribute' =>'best_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                ), 'left')   
        )
          ->addAttributeToFilter('best_flag', array('eq' => '1'));
```

Result = 7

```
->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute' =>'best_flag', array('eq' => '1')),
            array('attribute' =>'best_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
            ))
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute' =>'best_flag', array('eq' => '1')),
            array('attribute' =>'best_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
            ))
```

Result = 23

```
->addAttributeToFilter('best_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')    
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute' =>'best_flag', array('eq' => '1')),
            array('attribute' =>'best_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
            ))
```

Result = 10

```
->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute' =>'best_flag', array('eq' => '1')),
            array('attribute' =>'best_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
            ))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('best_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
```

Result = 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your update, it is not working because you switched everything to OR statements. Try this :

```
$yourmodel->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute' =>'best_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))),
            array('attribute' =>'best_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                ), 'left')   
        )
          ->addAttributeToFilter('best_flag', array('eq' => '1'));
```

This will render `(best_from date OR best_to_date) AND best_flag`
As I said, if you use @Emipro Technologies answer you will get OR and if you chain `->addAttributeToFilter()` you will get AND like you did at the beginning. If you want to do both, you just have to mix both syntaxes.

Comment: Thank you for your help and Sorry to answer late 
I try to use this code but result is show 7 is only result from flag (date from - date to result = 10 by flag = 7 i want to show 17)

Comment: and i try to use mix like (date to + flag) and (date from + flag) but result is show all of item

Comment: and i try to use only (date to + flag) result is show all of item same to

Comment: I'm really not sure what you want / need but please; make it simple. Also remember that if, before loading your collection, you do `echo $your_model->getSelect() `, you can print the corresponding sql request, which you can then, validate with your requested result or directly execute to your database, and maybe find a that you do have more a logic problem than a programming one ?

Comment: thank you for your help now i can get my collection now with '$your_model->getSelect()->orwhere("sql ");'

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for or condition

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
array(
    array('attribute'=> 'attribute1','like' => 'value1'),
    array('attribute'=> 'attribute2','like' => 'value2'),
    array('attribute'=> 'attribute3','like' => 'value3'),
 )
);
```

This will output a WHERE clause of the format:

```
WHERE ((attribute1 LIKE 'value1') OR (attribute2 LIKE 'value2') OR (attribute3 LIKE 'value3'))
```

Comment: thank you for your help i will try this code but it's don't work because 2 first condition of me just work with AND

Comment: @TenanoTalE `->addAttributeToFilter( insert Emipro 's answer here  ) -> addAttributeToFilter( insert your own code here )` will do an OR for the part related to Empire 's answer and an AND for your part.

Comment: @b.enoit.be i try to match 2 code but result is not correct 1st I try to set best_to_date with flag us same but result is show all of item is date from and not stop at date to

if i set best_from_date with flag result of flag is not show is not only date not expire

Answer (score 1):

This should to the trick:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('best_flag', array('in' => array(1,2,3,4)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this trick is not work 

result in sql is same 'AND(
 at_new_product.
 VALUE
  IN(1, 2, 3, 4)
)'

Comment: What goes before 'AND'?

Comment: '->addAttributeToFilter('best_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))    
            ->addAttributeToFilter('best_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left') '

Comment: i try to make code to select collection with date to - date from or flaq
in my collection from date is 10 by flaq is 7 (now not same product)

if this code condition is and collection = 0 if i can use of my collection will have 17